# Capture Windows Explorer Thumbnails as Images - Save as PNG Files

Tags: image, png, image-resizing, windows-explorer

I have a whole bunch of images in a directory on a Windows machine and I need to save a version of each photo as a thumbnail for another application.  Most of these images are large, (600 x 600 at least), so I was thinking I was going to have to open each in Photoshop and resize and then save as the smaller version.

But then I realized that the size that Windows explorer uses as the Large Icon view is exactly what I need.  If only I could quickly just save all these thumbnails stright out of Windows as copies of the photos but the exact size they appear in the explorer window...  If only...

Alternatively, I've seen batch image resizers (and I will most likely use one if this doesn't work) but what is the best way to accomplish what I'm going for here?  Is it possible to pull from Windows somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Vista or above, you can use [IShellItemImageFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the thumbnail either from the shell cache or generate one if necessary. For XP and earlier, you can call [IExtractImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761848%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Windows stores the thumbnails in each directory in a file called thumbs.db.  There are a couple of code projects around that would let you extract images from that file.

http://code.google.com/p/thumbs-viewer/

Or...  like you said you could use a batching type software.  If you can't find a batching software this is a fairly trivial thing to do in C# if you don't care about exif data or need to control the image quality too much.

Comment: Yah, I thought it might have something to do with the `thumbs.db` file.  That pesky thing may have just become my friend ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Updating Sheng Jiang dead link with current link

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/blob/docs/desktop-src/shell/samples-usingimagefactory.md

*#>I would love to reply, but need 50 points so I usually bail.<#*

- RickkeeC
- Chief Button Pusher since 1992